# jQuery get each attribute and append them to each new div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append, attr

I have a list of `<li>` with class `.boxitem`. In each `<li>` there as an attribute,

```
exmp---ee_list_itemident="142765"
```

I want to loop each boxitem and append them a new `div` in each `boxItem`:

```
<li class="boxItem auto-height first  grid_4">
    <div class="boxItem-wrap">
        <div class="item-name">
            <a ee_list_itemname="itemname= " ee_list_itemprice="0" ee_list_itemid="50011" ee_list_itemident="14d65" </a>
        </div>
        <div class="MiscFieldsIcons">
            <ul class="MiscIconUl">
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="pbcontact">
            <a class="openproductform" href="/product_contact_form.asp?itemident=2345&amp;subject_postfix="/>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>      
<li class="boxItem auto-height first  grid_4">
    <div class="boxItem-wrap">
        <div class="item-name">
            <a ee_list_itemname="itemname= " ee_list_itemprice="0" ee_list_itemid="32344" ee_list_itemident="142765" </a>
        </div>
        <div class="MiscFieldsIcons">
            <ul class="MiscIconUl">
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="pbcontact">
            <a class="openproductform" href="/product_contact_form.asp?itemident=2345&amp;subject_postfix="/>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

I tried to do something like this,

```
$(".boxItem").each(function() {
   var myclass = $(this).find( ".ee_product_click" ).attr('ee_list_itemident');
   var txt = $(this).text();
   $("<span>"+txt+"</span>").appendTo(".boxItem");
 });
```

and it doesn't work.

Comment: just forget  each box Item have different itemident attribute!

Comment: The HTML needs major improvement. I don't even know how to close these `div`s.

Comment: thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

This [`JSFiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/mnm3jhh1/1/) contains improved your HTML markup and javascript which get html content of each `.boxItem`